# Prevent javascript GET and Script

Tags: javascript, xss

Is there anyway to limit Javascript Get, Post request to a specified domain?
Also can I somehow disable JSONP?

I want to develop a web content framework where people can include javascripts in different pages but I don't want those scripts to access any other domain.

I am familiar with firefox "Content Security Policy" but unfortunately that is only applicable to firefox.

Answer (score 2):

It's "disabled" by default. If you want to "allow" json, you would have to add jsonp callback. Without it, js isn't able to retreive json response.

Comment: ok maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want to let people to add applications/addons to their sites (addons written for my framework by community). These 3rd party application are javascript applications and they get run under the same context/page as the rest of the html page. I don't want any of those javascripts to make a script call to another server. As you can see they can simply add a jsonp callback in their source and my users can't do anything (unless they go and check every single line of every addon)

Comment: I am thinking maybe the only way is to have the addons/apps as an iframe solution similar to what facebook does. But I am not sure if that is the only possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the users pick arbitrary javascripts, can you let them pick from a list of approved scripts, and rejects the edits if the scripts are not included from the right domain?
Or can you use some sort of a custom markup, where instead of being allowed to write -tags, they write [include="pluginname"], and you convert that to a script tag yourself, it the plugin with the given name is found?

Content Security Policy is also has limited support in Chrome, but currently it's not really what you want, as its support and penetration in the market is limited.

Comment: In essence what people are doing for these kinds of plugins, is that they are building frameworks of their own. Have a look at the widget standards from netvibes and iGoogle.

Comment: is there any open source tool to do this? Maybe a ruby dsl that translates to javascript?