# How to force <script> tag's src attribute following cross-domain policy?

Tags: jsonp

Let me explain by an example.

My website domain is `http://example.com`.

I want to configure my server that tells browser to disable every `<script>` tag from client where `src` attribute point to 3rd-party domain like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

There are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597289/nodejs-disable-jsonp-on-specific-routes/11597331#11597331) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130986/prevent-javascript-get-and-script) seem be similar to this, but all of their answers do not satisfy me.

Thank you.

Comment: I have very little idea about what you are talking about. You start out asking about JSONP then you switch to "every `<script>`", then you talk about web frameworks and then change your mind again to talk about a specific JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Are you asking how to write an HTTP server using JavaScript, that will run on Node.JS and will strip any `<script>` tags out of any HTML that it outputs?

Comment: I want to disable all requests from client that using `<script>` tag with `src` attribute point to another domain (jquery.com for example). It will pass `same domain policy` by default. So that I want to _configure server_ (by some headers) to _tell browser_ to disallow request like this

Comment: @Quentin: `JSONP` is a request method that wraps a request to **any domain** in a `<script>` tag (by `src` attribute) regardless of the `same-domain policy`, as I know (please tell me if I'm wrong with this definition).
If my definition is correct, there is obvious relationship between `JSONP` and `<script>` tag.

Comment: All JSONP requests are made using `<script>` tags, but not all `<script>` tags make JSONP requests. Loading jQuery is not a JSONP request.

Comment: @Quentin: oh, sorry I think I've messed them up. I will edit my question now. Thank you